# Ruby classes pass variables between

Tags: ruby, class

Is there any way to pass variables between classes? 
I have the next code.

```
module Test
  class Super
    def initialize(name)
      @name = name
    end
  end

  class Upper
    def test
      puts @name
    end
  end
end

a=Test::Super.new('My name')
b=Test::Upper.new()
b.test()
```

Thank you!

Comment: What variable do you want to share between what classes?

Comment: If you had another `Test::Super` instance, e.g. `a2=Test::Super.new('My other name')`, what would `b.test()` return?

Answer (score 1):

No, because a is an *instance* of the class. Two answers for you;

1) It's better programming practice to have send `a` to `b`.  So you'd do something like this; (assuming `attr_reader :name`)

```
class Upper
  def test(s)
    s.name
  end
end

a = Test::Super.new('My Name')
u = Test::Upper.new
u.test(a)
```

or you could have it part of the setup; I won't give you all the code, but here's how it'd look

```
a = Test::Super.new('My name')
b = Test::Upper.new(a)
b.test
=> 'My name'
```

Neither of these examples is particularly good practice for classes but I imagine you have a more specific use case you're trying to achieve that has been anonymised for the purpose of this question :)

Comment: also avoid `Super` because it's a reserved ruby word

Comment: `Super` is not a reserved ruby word. Ruby is case-sensitive.

Comment: Agree, but, wait til they do something like `super = Test::Super.new` and wonder why it isn't working. :)

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason instances of the class `Upper` need to have an access to the internals of instances of the class `Super`, it means you have a design flaw.

One possible way would be `Super` needs to **expose** the variable via a getter:

```
module Test
  class Super
    def initialize(name)
      @name = name
    end
    def name
      @name
    end
  end
end
```

Now you might get the `name` with `Test::Super.new("my name").name`.

---

Another possibility is `Upper` is actually a subclass of `Super`:

```
class Upper < Super
  def test
    puts @name
  end
end
```

Now `Test::Upper.new("my name").test` will print `"my name"`, because `Upper` *derives* the implementation from `Super`.

---

Also, one might use an instance variable on the enclosing module level:

```
module Test
  def self.name=(name)
    @name = name
  end
  def self.name
    @name
  end

  class Super
    def initialize(name)
      Test.name = name
    end
  end

  class Upper
    def test
      puts Test.name
    end
  end
end
```

This would print:

```
▶ Test::Super.new("my")
#⇒ #<Test::Super:0x0055dae57fe390>
▶ Test::Upper.new.test
#⇒ "my"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of class variables in module, which is supported natively by Ruby.

You can do:

```
module Test

  @@name = ''

  class Super
    def initialize(name)
      @@name = name
    end
  end

  class Upper
    def test
      puts @@name
    end
  end
end

a=Test::Super.new('My name')
b=Test::Upper.new()
b.test()
```

Comment: Please never ever suggest using class variables in ruby. It has **many** drawbacks for no value. One should better use an instance variable on class level of `Test`. Also, void declaration of `@@name` makes no sense.